# Calling SQL procedure in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have the following method in Java, which should call and execute a SQL procedure:

```
public void insertDocSubject(DocSubject docSubject) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try  {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.createSQLQuery("SELECT create_subject_relation(" + docSubject.getDocumentFk() + ", " + docSubject.getDocSubjectTypeFk() + ", " + docSubject.getSubjectFk() + ", " + docSubject.getDocSubjectRelationTypeFk() + ", '" + docSubject.getNote() + "');");
        } finally {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            if(session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

After running it, nothing happens but procedure is also not executed. I also tried running the procedure by hand and then it worked like it should.

I also tried a method I read about on Google, which suggested the following function.

```
session.getNamedQuery("create_subject_relation").setParameter("doc_id", docSubject.getDocumentFk()).setParameter("sub_type", docSubject.getDocSubjectTypeFk()).setParameter("sub_id", docSubject.getSubjectFk()).setParameter("rel_type", docSubject.getDocSubjectRelationTypeFk()).setParameter("note", docSubject.getNote());
```

But as with the first method, it didn't work. Is there something I'm doing wrong or why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating the query, but not executing it, i.e., invoking the "list" method on it.